# Why is the character space of a Banach algebra weak $\ast$ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ denote a unital commutative Banach algebra and let $\Sigma(A)$ denote its character space.

Why is $\Sigma(A) \cup \{0\}$ weak $\ast$ closed in the closed unit ball of $A^\ast$? Is $\Sigma(A) \cup \{0\}$ weak $\ast$ closed in $A^\ast$?

Comment: The character space is the set of all (continuous) algebra homomorphisms $A\to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, except the zero homomorphism is excluded.

Comment: You can find the proof in Naimark "Normed Rings".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Sigma(A) \cup \{0\}$ is precisely the set of multiplicative elements of $A^\ast$. Therefore

$$\Sigma(A)\cup \{0\} = \bigcap_{x,y\in A} \underbrace{\left\lbrace \varphi\in A^\ast : \varphi(xy) - \varphi(x)\varphi(y) = 0 \right\rbrace}_{M_{x,y}}$$

is weak* closed as the intersection of the weak* closed sets $M_{x,y}$.

To see that $M_{x,y}$ is weak* closed, for $x,y$ arbitrary but fixed, consider $F \colon A^\ast \to \mathbb{C}^3$, given by

$$F(\varphi) = \bigl(\varphi(xy),\varphi(x),\varphi(y) \bigr).$$

$F$ is weak* continuous by the definition of the weak* and product topologies (on $A^\ast$ resp. $\mathbb{C}^3$).

Let $P = \{ (u,v,w) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : u - v\cdot w = 0\}$. By the continuity of multiplication and subtraction, $P$ is closed.

Hence $M_{x,y} = F^{-1}(P)$ is weak* closed as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map.

Comment: And $M_{x,y}$ is closed because it is the inverse image $T_{xy}^{-1}\{0\}$ where $T_x: A^\ast \to \mathbb C$ is the evaluation at $x$?

Comment: Nah, that would be $\{\varphi \in A^\ast : \varphi(xy)=0\}$. I'm not sure I understand this.

Comment: For $x,y$ arbitrary but fixed, consider $F \colon A^\ast \to \mathbb{C}^3$, given by $$F(\varphi) = \bigl(\varphi(xy),\varphi(x),\varphi(y) \bigr).$$ That is weak* continuous. Let $P = \{ (u,v,w) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : u - v\cdot w = 0\}$. By the continuity of multiplication and subtraction, $P$ is closed. Hence $M_{x,y} = F^{-1}(P)$ is weak* closed.

Comment: Isn't $$\Sigma(A) = \bigcap_{x,y\in A} \underbrace{\left\lbrace \varphi\in A^\ast : \varphi(xy) - \varphi(x)\varphi(y) = 0 \right\rbrace}_{M_{x,y}}$$ not 
$$\Sigma(A)\cup \{0\} = \bigcap_{x,y\in A} \underbrace{\left\lbrace \varphi\in A^\ast : \varphi(xy) - \varphi(x)\varphi(y) = 0 \right\rbrace}_{M_{x,y}}$$?

Comment: The intersection is the set of all multiplicative linear functionals on $A$. The $0$-functional is multiplicative too, but it doesn't belong to $\Sigma(A)$.

Comment: Oops, you are right of course, sorry.

Comment: Couldn't we say that $M_{x,y}$ is the zero set of the continuous function $e_{xy}-e_xe_y$?

Comment: Although I guess the reason why $e_{xy}-e_xe_y$ is continuous is that the function $(u,v,w)\mapsto u-v.w$ is continuous.

Comment: @HritRoy Indeed. And one can consider the continuity of $e_{xy} - e_x e_y$ as obvious (sums and products of continuous complex-valued functions are always continuous). But in view of the comments I included the argument in the answer.