# Character space of abelian Banach algebra is weak* closed in the unit ball of dual space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Say $A$ is an abelian Banach algebra and $\Omega(A)\subset A^* := B(A, \mathbf{C})$ is the set of non-zero algebra homomorphisms. Consider now $\Omega(A)$ with the weak$^*$ topology.

I am trying to understand why $\Omega(A) \subset S$, where $S$ is the unit ball in $A^*$, is a weak$^ *$ closed subset of $S$ when $A$ is unital. The thing that bugs me is that I think that $\Omega(A)$ is already a closed subset of $S$, without the assumption that $A$ is unital.

The proof that I have in mind is just by considering a net $(\phi_{\lambda})_{ \lambda \in I } \subset \Omega(A)$ that converges in the weak$^ *$ topology to some $\phi \in S$. We want to show then that for any $a, b \in A$ we have that $\phi(ab) - \phi(a)\phi(b) = 0$.

Consider then the following estimate
$$|\phi(ab) - \phi(a)\phi(b)| \leq |\phi(ab) - \phi_{\lambda}(ab)| + |\phi_{\lambda}(a)| \cdot |\phi_{\lambda}(b) - \phi(b)| + |\phi(b)| \cdot |\phi_{\lambda}(a) - \phi(a)|. $$
Now we can bound $|\phi_{\lambda}(a)| \leq ||a||$ as $||\phi_{\lambda}|| \leq 1$; similarly $|\phi(b)| \leq ||b||$. It follows by the pointwise net convergence of the $\phi_{\lambda}$'s that we can make the righthand side arbitrary small.

I cannot seem to find a flaw in this reasoning. Let me know if there is something fundamentally wrong. There are related threads to this question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746587/need-help-understanding-this-proof-about-gelfand-spectrum), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634645/why-is-the-character-space-of-a-banach-algebra-weak-ast-closed), but none of them address this particular problem.

Comment: I think you have forgotten to show that $\phi \neq 0$ and it seems that in the non unital case it might be possible to construct a net of non zero homomorphisms that converges to 0 in the weak* topology.

Comment: @jd27 Oh oh oh, yes you are absolutely right! Thanks for pointing it out, haha. Now it makes sense if we assume $A$ to be unital, then this is automatically the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the comment may have answered your question, but it boils down to we know that each character (*when $A$ is unital*) $\varphi$ is actually a *unital* $*$-homomorphism, so in particular, if $\psi_i \longrightarrow \psi \in S$ is a net of characters converging $w^{*}$ to some $\psi \in S$, then by definition of $w^{*}$-convergence: $$\psi(1_{A}) = \lim_i \psi_i(1_{A}) = \lim_i 1 = 1 \neq 0$$ so $\psi \neq 0$ and thus combined with your above argument shows $\psi \in \Omega(A)$.

If you don't assume $A$ is unital, you can get a net of characters tending to $0$ $w^{*}$.  For example, Take $A = C_0(\mathbb{R})$.  Then $(\text{ev}_n)^{\infty}_{n=1} \subset \Omega(A)$ by $\text{ev}_n(f) = f(n)$.  Then $\text{ev}_n \rightarrow 0 \notin \Omega(A)$ $w^{*}$.